# Passing value from a textbox in javascript into jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I hava a textbox in javascript. How can pass the value in the textbox into a jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By submitting the form containing the text box, or by reading the box value in JavaScript and sending an AJAX request to the JSP.

Comment: can you give me the code

Comment: No I can't. Do your own homework.

Comment: how can i read the boxvalue/

Comment: Have you heard about Google? What happens when you google for "read a text box value in JavaScript"? Some things need to be learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the questions you asked to sir.Jb Nizet

for form submission

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

for Ajax submission

http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/

of course finally

http://www.google.com

for basic queries .

All the best and welcome to web development .  :)